# Channel > Entry > Relationship > Grid > Field

Tags: templates, relationships, grid

I have a channel called "videos" with a bunch of entries in it. One of the fields in this channel is a relationship to another channel called "person". The "person" channel has a field called "facts" which is a grid with one column called "fact".

When I render this template, I successfully get the name of each person as well as a node for each `<Fact>` in the "facts" grid.

```
<Videos>
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos"}
    <Video>
        <Subject>{person:title}</Subject>
        <Facts>
            {person:facts}
            <Fact></Fact>
            {/person:facts}
        </Facts>
    </Video>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</Videos>
```

However I can't figure out how to get the content of the grid to appear. I've tried:

```
<Fact>{fact}</Fact>
<Fact>{facts:fact}</Fact>
<Fact>{person:facts:fact}</Fact>
```

With the last two, I get an error:

```
Message: Undefined variable: field_ids
Filename: libraries/Grid_parser.php
Line Number: 103
```

I am running EE Core 2.7.2 (still evaluating it) under PHP 5.4.11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you were missing the relationship tag pair for your `person` field. Try this:

```
<Videos>
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos"}
    {person}
    <Video>
        <Subject>{person:title}</Subject>
        <Facts>
            {person:facts}
            <Fact>{person:facts:fact}</Fact>
            {/person:facts}
        </Facts>
    </Video>
   {/person}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</Videos>
```

Comment: Yes, see the things I tried above -- shouldn't one of those have worked?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Got it -- I'm learning how the scoping works. I need to read the relationship docs more clearly.